# Is this vector field complete?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, curves, vector-fields

Consider the [vector field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_field) $F:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$, defined by $F(x,y) = \begin{pmatrix}y \\x^2\end{pmatrix}$.

[image: Vector field plot]

Can it be shown that $F$ is not complete?

Equivalently: Is there an explicit [integral curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_curve) $\varphi:I \to \mathbb{R}^2$ with $I \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ satisfying $\dot{\varphi}(t)=F(\varphi(t))$, which is not defined on all of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: With a bit of effort one can show that the possible integral curves of $F$ are curves $\varphi:I \to \mathbb{R}^2$ of the form $$\varphi(t) = \left(\sqrt[3]{\frac{3}{2}y(t)^2 - \frac{3}{2}y_0^2 + y_0^3 } , y(t) \right)$$ with starting value $\varphi(0)=(x_0,y_0)$ if $y(0)=y_0$ for appropriately chosen $y:I \to \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\varphi(t)=(x(t),y(t))$; then $\dot{\varphi}(t)=F(\varphi(t))$ is equivalent to
$(\dot{x},\dot{y})=(y,x^2)$, which implies $\ddot{x}=\dot{y}=x^2$. Integrating it, we obtain

$\frac{1}{2}\dot{x}^2=\frac{1}{3}(x^3+C)$,

where $C=\frac{1}{2}y_0^2-\frac{1}{3}x_0^3$. Integrating again, we obtain

$t=\int_{x_0}^x\frac{du}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}(u^3+C)}}$,

where we assumed that $\dot{x}(0)=y_0>0$ in order to select the positive square root of $\dot{x}^2$, and also to ensure the convergence of the integral at the lower limit of integration. Since the integral also converges in the limit $x\to\infty$, it follows that $x(t)$ is defined only for $t\in[0,T)$, where

$T=\int_{x_0}^{\infty}\frac{du}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}(u^3+C)}}<\infty$.

This shows that $F$ is not complete. $\square$